# Form .each() and .val() jQuery loop

Tags: jquery

Put simply, I want the background colour to change to green once all of the text inputs inside a *.wrap* div have a value in them.

At the moment the colour in the first .wrap div wont change to green until the second *.wrap* div also has values?

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <input type="text" /><br />
        <input type="text" /><br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="wrap">
        <input type="text" /><br />
        <input type="text" /><br />
        <input type="text" /><br />
    </div>
```

```
    $('.wrap').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            var trigger = false;
            $('input:text').each(function () {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    trigger = true;
                }
            });
            trigger ? $('input:text').parent().css('background-color', 'red') : $('input:text').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to `$.trigger()` an event when someone changes the value of an input. Not just loop over them once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

    $('input').each(function() {
        check($(this));
    });

    $('textarea').each(function() {
        check($(this));
    });

    function check($toCheck) {
        $toCheck.change(function() {

            var missingVal = false;
            $toCheck.siblings().each(function() {
                if($(this).context.nodeName == "INPUT") {
                    if(!$(this).val()) {
                        missingVal = true;
                    }
                }
            })

            if($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
                if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                    missingVal = true;
                }
            } else {
                if(!$(this).val()) {
                    missingVal = true;
                }   
            }

            if(missingVal) {
                $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'green');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this work great but now that it's working how can I add, a checkbox and or a textarea and still make it work.

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing with other input elements, you may have to adjust this line of code, however:

if($(this).context.nodeName == "INPUT") {

to something like

if($(this).context.nodeName == "INPUT" || $(this).context.nodeName == "TEXTAREA") {

Comment: I amended the original so it will now work for those input types.

Answer (score 3):

Bind change in input elements :

```
$(this).find('input').change(function () {
```

---

Here's the full code with additional changes:

```
$('.wrap').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input').change(function () {
            var trigger = false;
            var dish = $(this);
            dish.each(function () {
                if (!dish.val()) {
                    trigger = true;
                }
            });
            trigger ? dish.parent().css('background-color', 'red') : dish.parent().css('background-color', 'green');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `div` elements do not have a `change` event. Change your `change` handler to be placed onto the `input` elements instead:

```
$(this).find('input').change(function() { ... });
```

Secondly, your `$('input:text')` selector isn't specific to the `.wrap` element you're iterating over, but is instead selecting *all* `input:text` elements matched on the entire page.

Change all instances of `$('input:text')` to `$(this).parent().find('input:text')`.

```
$(this).parent().find('input:text').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
         trigger = true;
    }
});
```

This will select any `input:text` element contained within the parent of the `input` element which had its `change` event triggered (the related `.wrap` element).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that about the change event.